# run something as another user without admin

Tags: linux

i have two users without passwords "plex" & "debian-transmission". I need "debian-transmission" to be able to tell "plex" to execute

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/plexmediaserver";/usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex\ Media\ Scanner --scan --refresh --section 2
```

but I cannot figure out how to do that successfully

Comment: Why does it have to be plex running the code?  Would it be possible to add debian-transmission to the plex group and then set appropriate group permissions on `/usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex\ Media\ Scanner` (there by the debian-transmission user would be able to run the script directly)?  Would a NOPASS sudo policy work?

Comment: @MrAlias export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/plexmediaserver" Can cause issues for other users.

Answer (score 0):

write a C wrapper like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    system("export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/plexmediaserver";/usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex\ Media\ Scanner --scan --refresh --section 2");
}


gcc -o suid suid.c
sudo chown plex suid
sudo chmod 4755 plex
```

or use sudo